# jQuery script works when in HTML but not in external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  a test using jquery that s work fine when in html file but when I put it in anexternal js file it doesn t work , help please , I need it to continue my application. query.js is in /js directory

HTML : detail.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"  prefix="springform"  %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ajouter annonce</title>
<link type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<link type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >

<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/query.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script> 

</head>
<body class="body2">

<div id="test" class="test" > Allo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Js file : query.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
        alert("hello");
    })
 });
```

Comment: Any error in browser console?

Comment: To have confirmation that the external file was loaded maybe add a `console.log('file loaded');` line there.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? try adding query.js after main.js

Comment: By the looks of it it should be working unless the file has failed to loaded due to invalid url.

Comment: thaks you guys, @Znaneswar you are right the problem was in the path    :   src="/js/query.js" instead of    src="js/query.js"> , foret the /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of the comments, I found the error was in the path :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/query.js"></script>
```

instead of :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/query.js"></script>
```